# IoT Reference Implementations for Urban Sanitation

Tags: mobile-applications

Does anyone have any good examples of IoT usage in the area of urban sanitation, particularly for low income settings?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unfortunately this question is far to broad to be a good question for this site... You'll need to have a specific question of exactly what you're trying to do.  Show what research you have done so far, and explain your goals with your project.  Thanks!

Comment: Agreed. BUT, I do like this question and hope that the OP will add more detail, so that the question will opened again and can receive answers.